# concrete class method keeps throwing an exception from abstract class despite implementation

Tags: java, class, exception, abstract

I have an abstract class Automobile which has an unimplemented method called move
so

```
public abstract class Automobile {
   public void move() {
       throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
   }
}
```

I have a concrete class which extends my abstract class and implements the move method.My problem is the method keeps throwing an `UnsupportedOperationException`

```
public class Car extends Automobile{
  int x; 
   public void move(){
    x++;
   }
}
```

Comment: Uh...that's because you're explicitly throwing an exception. I suggest you rethink your abstraction.

Comment: Please show the code of the concrete class too.

Comment: Why have you created an implementation of move() in your abstract class rather than making it abstract?

Comment: How you are calling the `overriding` method of derived class?

Comment: My concrete class extends the Abstract class.In regards to throwing the exception explicityl,I have it that way because a few classes are extending the abstract class and some of theses classes dont implement the method in the abstract class

Comment: You mean some Automobiles are not able to move? Tell me which ones so I don't buy them ;)

Comment: Add an @Override annotation before Car's move() implementation.  Also, post the invoking code and stack trace.  Don't be stingy with the information.

Comment: With that implementation (and if there's no other implementation of Automobile, including anonymous ones) then there's NO WAY to throw the exception. SO the problem probably comes from the fact you're calling the method on something that's not a Car.

Answer (score 3):

It could be for many reasons in your concrete class: maybe your concrete doesn't actually extends `Foo`? Or maybe it calls `super.move()` somewhere in its body.

Instead of throwing an exception, the correct way is to define the class and method as `abstract` to force subclasses to override it.

```
public abstract class Foo {
    public abstract void move();
}
```

Please note if `Foo` only has abstract methods, like in the example above, that's an `interface` that you want, not an abstract class. Also, you should name it to define a behaviour

```
public interface Moving { 
    void move();
}
```

And then:

```
public class MovingObject implements Moving {
    ....
    @Override
    public void move() {
       // your implementation
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: my abstract class has a few methods that have implementations.My concrete class that extends my abstract class has the concrete implmentation

Comment: Ok then :) You should post the code of the implementation, at least the one for the move() method, and the calling code, so we can see why it throws the exception. My guess is on a super.move()

Comment: I have added an implementation to my code ,Please have a look

Comment: Throwing the exception in the base class is not incorrect.  See java.util.AbstractList for examples.  Java's Collections framework contains a number of optional operations.  I'll admit, the given case of Automobile having move() as an optional operation seems strange.  I think I'd even handle the case of Yugo extends Automobile without throwing the UnsupportedOperationException.  Nevertheless, the OP's implementation is not incorrect.

Comment: @user371320 in your opinion,Why is my concrete implementation throwing an exception

Comment: You're probably calling the method on something that's not a Car

Comment: Please edit your question to include the calling code and the stack trace you are receiving.  Then we can probably help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling super.move() in your implementation class? Eclipse generates that call by default if you used Source->Override/Implement Methods...

Otherwise I think, that you did not override the method correctly.

Comment: No,I am not using super.move().In my class that extends the abstract class ,I Have a concrete implementation of the method